# Capture matched pattern in a cp/mv command

Tags: bash, shell, regex

I want to rename files that are named like `db_backup_2019_11_22-12_13_00.gz` to `db_dump_2019_11_22-12_13_00.sql.gz`.

Is there a way to do this using pattern match? I mean like this:

```
mv db_backup_*-*.gz db_dump_$1-$2.sql.gz
```

where `$1`, `$2` are matched parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [rename command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm):

```
rename 's/backup(.+?)(?=\.gz$)/dump$1.sql/' db_backup*
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/                  # substitute
    backup              # literally "backup"
    (.+?)               # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
    (?=\.gz$)           # positive lookahead, make sure we have ".gz" after
/                   # WITH
    dump                # literally "dump"
    $1                  # content of group 1
    .sql                # literally ".sql"
/                   # end substitute
```

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation!

Comment: @Hirurg103: You're welcome, glad it helps.